# Connecting to ConnectWise API in Python

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to connect to the ConnectWise API using Python, but I keep running into "400 Client Error: Bad Request" errors.

When I use "https://api-na.myconnectwise.net/v4_6_version/apis/3.0/" as the url, I get an "invalid token" message, and when I use the codebase shown in my company info as opposed to "v4_6_version," I get a message that says

> "code": "ConnectWiseApi", "message": "UserNotAuthenticated", "errors": null"

Has anyone run into these sorts of problems? From what I've found, it seems like this is caused by incorrect public/private keys, but I've tried with several different keys and keep getting the same message. I think it might be my url that's wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you're using https and you're getting a valid response message from the remote server as indicated by that error message, the problem isn't with your public/private keys. The documentation will likely talk about about an API Key or other bearer token, or possibly even a username/password combination that you will need. Then you will likely have to set the appropriate headers to be able to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Three components you need:

1. header called "clientid" with the value of your client ID from here
   https://developer.connectwise.com/ClientID
2. basic authentication username = `company+public key`
3. basic authentication password = `private key`

I was able to get 200OK response trying to authenticate as above with Postman